# No 'qtjambi-deployment.xml' found in classpath, loading libraries via 'java.library.path'

Tags: java, qt, qt-jambi

I am trying to install QT Jambi from Java, but I get the following error, which I do not know how to interpret.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.trolltech.qt.QtJambiObject. <clinit> (Unknown Source) 
at programa.Main.main (Main.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Loading library failed, progress so far: No 'qtjambi-deployment.xml' found in classpath, loading libraries via 'java.library.path' Loading library: 'libQtCore.so.4' ...
 - using 'java.library.path'
at com.trolltech.qt.internal.NativeLibraryManager.loadNativeLibrary (Unknown Source)
at com.trolltech.qt.internal.NativeLibraryManager.loadQtLibrary (Unknown Source)
at com.trolltech.qt.Utilities.loadQtLibrary (Unknown Source)
at com.trolltech.qt.Utilities.loadQtLibrary (Unknown Source) at com.trolltech.qt.QtJambi_LibraryInitializer. <clinit> (Unknown Source) ...
2 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Library 'libQtCore.so.4' was not found in 'java.library.path' = / usr / local / java / jdk1.8.0
```

The development environment is NetBeans on Linux Mint. Can anybody help me?

Comment: How did you install qt-jambi? Is there a Mint package or did you just do a generic install? Which installation instructions did you follow?

Comment: I fixed it by changing the version. In Mint, it is only to decompress and import in each java project